Does Blazor Server's single-threaded emulation ignore JavaScript interop?
I ran into an issue today with a component that wraps a JS library that can affect the Blazor component's bound value. Updating the value of the Mask parameter would result in the JavaScript code running multiple times.
[Parameter]
public string Value { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public Mask Mask { get; set; }

private Mask _mask;
private bool _maskNeedsUpdate;

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    // ... Handle other parameters.

    if (_mask != Mask)
    {
        _mask = Mask;
        _maskNeedsUpdate = true;
    }
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    // ... initialize JS mask on first render.

    if (_maskNeedsUpdate)
    {
        var valueAfterUpdate = await Js.InvokeAsync<string>("updateMask", _mask);
        if (valueAfterUpdate != Value)
        {
            await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(valueAfterUpdate);
        }

        _maskNeedsUpdate = false; // <-- This causes problems.
    }
}

It's almost as if that ValueChanged.InvokeAsync() call triggers a re-render in parallel, which causes a second JS interop call to be queued since the flag is still true. But I doubt it since it's literally set to false on the very next line (meanwhile, all EventCallback.InvokeAsync() seems to do is essentially call StateHasChanged() in the parent component and call its callback).
Changing the code to set the flag before calling JS seems to have fixed the issue.
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    // ... initialize JS mask on first render.

    if (_maskNeedsUpdate)
    {
        _maskNeedsUpdate = false; // <-- Toggle flag before awaiting JS.

        var valueAfterUpdate = await Js.InvokeAsync<string>("updateMask", _mask);
        if (valueAfterUpdate != Value)
        {
            await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(valueAfterUpdate);
        }
    }
}

This fix kind of confuses me, though, because according to the docs:

Blazor uses a synchronization context (SynchronizationContext) to enforce a single logical thread of execution. A component's lifecycle methods and event callbacks raised by Blazor are executed on the synchronization context.
Blazor's server-side synchronization context attempts to emulate a single-threaded environment so that it closely matches the WebAssembly model in the browser, which is single threaded. This emulation is scoped only to an individual circuit, meaning two different circuits can run in parallel. At any given point in time within a circuit, work is performed on exactly one thread, which yields the impression of a single logical thread. No two operations execute concurrently within the same circuit.

My understanding is that the single-thread emulation shouldn't allow my Blazor components to "re-render in parallel" while my JavaScript is still running (and, looking at the Blazor source code, OnAfterRenderAsync() is eventually awaited). But, then why does moving the flag up before the JS interop call fix my issue? Even if the parent re-renders, wouldn't the single-thread emulation prevent it from re-rendering in parallel?
I'd like to know if I'm supposed to watch out for race conditions when designing components that make calls to the JavaScript interop.
The above example was a simple enough fix, but I have other components that wrap JS libraries that have much more complex behavior where both the C# and JS sides can alter bound parameters, and "just moving the flag higher" isn't going to work for some of them if the component can re-render in parallel.

Are you trying to apply a mask i.e. a pattern to an input?  Perhaps show more code.  My reason for asking is you may not need to resort to JSInterop.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I have some components that use masks, but I also have others that wrap around more complex libraries. I used the mask code as an example because it had the simplest fix. We've yet to find how to fix the more complex ones. Also, we're using a JS library to mask our inputs in Blazor because, otherwise, you get bad UX where the characters appear in the input before the Blazor event handlers erases them. The only alternative we've found is to do what MudBlazor does and hijack key events and bubble them up to Blazor. That won't work for different component types.

See this article of mine on about OnAfterRenderrAsync - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/OnAfterRender.html.  It demonstrates some console logging that you probably want to use to document the sequence.  Can you provide a [MRE] of an example component of yours?  Happy to have a look.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis (1/2) Sorry for the late reply (we had a long weekend). Your linked post actually helped clear some stuff about when OnAfterRenderAsync fires (and how it can fire multiple times). Our fear with fixing the more complex components was "What happens if there's multiple race conditions where the JS finishes and triggers a render, a render is already happening from a parameter change, and the user enters stuff that queues up more of everything? How do we handle that? With our own queue?" Reading up on how the Blazor synchronization context works also helped. (Continued...)

(2/2) In our case, it seems the issue is that EventCallback.InvokeAsync() is causing a second OnAfterRenderAsync() to be queued, but since that has its own async logic in it, the flag isn't updated before the second one starts running. Moving the flag up seems to solve the issue, even with the more complex components. Thanks for the help!


My understanding is that the single-thread emulation shouldn't allow my Blazor components to "re-render in parallel"

That is the wrong assumption. Async and multi-threaded are not the same. Blazor's rendering is async (interleaved) and yes, a new render can happen when you do an await anywhere. That it all happens on the same single thread is not so relevant.
This is covered by a Note in the docs that states:

Asynchronous actions performed in lifecycle events might not complete before a component is rendered.

So your original code did have a race condition and setting the flag earlier is indeed the fix.

but I have other components that wrap JS libraries that have much more complex behavior

You'll have to look at that case-by-case. I don't think there is a general solution except maybe to not use the AfterRender event to update data. It should be possible to move that logic to OnParamsSet.

Ah, I saw the "before a component is rendered" part and wrongfully assumed they meant the initial render, not the re-renders. "It should be possible to move that logic to OnParamsSet." I was under the impression we should only call JS code from OnAfterRenderAsync() to avoid issues related to the component' rendering of elements (i.e. if a re-render causes element references to go stale).

Also, about the Async vs Multi-threaded bit: My understanding is that asynchronous code uses the underlying SynchronizationContext to determine how to handle async operations, so I thought the SynchronizationContext trying to emulate a single-threaded environment would translate to async methods running in a similar fashion. Should that not be the case?

To the last bit, yes, you can just think of it as single-threaded. But it is still async so rendering and eventhadlers can and will run in parallel. Maybe look for the "there is no thread" article by Steven Cleary. .
